# How to show ViewController under the didSelectItemAt indexPath function ? (without storyboard)

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Have a nice weekend. I have problem about that under the didSelectItemAt indexPath function I want to go new view controller which is show details and each cell must have different view controller (it will change according to data which are came from protocol). I tried lots of way to do that but I can't figured out. I call present and push view controller codes but its also not working because navigationController code can't work under didSelectItemAt function. Lastly I tried that:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let homecon = HomeController()
    homecon.showDetailPage() }


func showDetailPage() {
    let newView = pageDetail()
    self.present(newView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

(showDetailPage function from HomeController). But that code also gave error which is

> 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'.

So I can't solve it. How can I solve it please help me. Have a nice work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `HomeController` is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` and a collectionViewController can not be initialized without it's layout!

So use this initializer instead:

```
let homecon = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
```

Oh and it's just the start of the week here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when I tried that gave me that : Warning: Attempt to present ....  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!.

Comment: This is the answer to the question you asked with the error you posted. That is another question and have another reason. Please feel free to ask another question if you need any further help.

Comment: You are right. I have to research about that error. If I can't figure out let me say you! Thanks.